# MySQL replication error

Tags: mysql, replication, slave

On the slave server this appears when I run `show proccesslist`:

> State: Has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it

The slave servers don't accept more queries from the application.

Any idea why MySQL is doing this?

Comment: Was one server down for a short time?

Comment: Is a disk full at slave?

Answer (score 2):

This means,

That there are no changes on the Master node and the slave wait for changes.

so "has read all realay log" he has read all of them.
Now he wait the there something happen on the Master node and he can fetch any changes from the master.